# Hacer click sobre control dentro de iframe con Jquery o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sesiones, iframe

Tengo un `iframe` dentro de mi página, lo que sucede es que dentro de este `iframe` (página web de otro dominio), para acceder a unas funciones deben crear su sesión e ingresar, hasta ahí no hay lio, el problema ocurre que cuando un usuario deja su sesión abierta dentro de la página que llama este `iframe`, cuando otra persona ingresa a esta misma opción encuentra la sesión de la otra persona activada.

Lo que quiero hacer es:

**1)** Usar la función `.click()` de `jquery` para pulsar el botón que cierra la sesión de la persona (como si ella lo pulsara).

**2)** Ejecutar la *función* en `javascript` existente en esa página que envía la acción de cerrar sesión; la tengo identificada, pero al intentar acceder a ella me emite una excepción del `DOM` (algo con el `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).

**3)** Eliminar la variable de sesión `ASP` (`ASP.NET_SessionId`) que genera esa página dentro de mi `iframe` para que se resetee la sesión que había creado el usuario.

Cualquiera de las opciones me serviría, solo **necesito una forma de poder hacer que la sesión (si la dejaron abierta) se cierre** siempre que accedan a la opción.

---

Agrego:

El error que me aparece en la alternativa dos es este

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "localhost:49794";
>   from accessing a cross-origin frame. at :1:49

Y el método que utilice para intentar acceder a esa función lo tome de esta página: http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/315/como-se-puede-ejecutar-el-codigo-javascript-de-un-de-la-pagina/

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que tienes hasta ahora y que errores te da? Prueba  a hacer un [mcve]. un saludo

Comment: No sale mejor solo cerrar la sesión por inactividad con PHP? Es decir, destruir la sesión después de cierto tiempo.

Comment: El error que me aparece es ´Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:49794" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:49´

Comment: Eso me sale cuando intento ejecutar la función que tiene la página que llamo en el iframe que cierra la sesión, el método que usé está aquí http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/315/como-se-puede-ejecutar-el-codigo-javascript-de-un-de-la-pagina/

Comment: @LuisFernando no puedo porque es una página en ASP.net al igual que la que estoy llamando en el iframe, solo que la página que llamo no es de mi dominio, es completamente aparte de mi